# Texfield sending null value to web service

Tags: ios, soap, uitextfield

I have 3 `UITextField`'s,  date1, date2(`UIDatePicker`) and station name(Like combobox). First of all I must load all station name to station name `UITextField`.When I enter A listing starting with A station name.I select first date,second date and station name for send to web service for display fields on labels.I want to sending station ID when I select station name.Every station name have station ID.

Anybody have idea or sample ? Thanks.

Comment: It will be great to have some code to work with. You should also edit your question a little bit, is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using picker view then try this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 3;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if(row == 0)
    {
        return @"Station 1";

    }
    else if(row == 1)
    {
        return @"Station 2";
    }
    else if (row==2)
    {
        return @"Station 3";

    }
    return @"";

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(row == 0)
    {
        self.int_Stationid = 1;

    }
    else if(row == 1)
    {
        self.int_Stationid = 2;

    }
    else if (row==2)
    {
        self.int_Stationid = 3;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have 770 station name and ID.I want to search in textfield like search in google.